# Is $P^{NPI}$ different from $P^{NP}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np-intermediate

Can we prove that for every language $L\in\mathsf{NP}$ that is not $\mathsf{NP}$-hard (this assumes $\mathsf P \ne \mathsf{NP}$), $\mathsf{P}^L \ne \mathsf{P}^{\text{SAT}}$?  Alternately, can this be proven under any reasonable assumptions?

Comment: I think this question has a silly answer: Let $L\in\mathsf P\subseteq\mathsf{NP}$, then certainly $\mathsf P^L\neq \mathsf P^{\text{SAT}}$ once you assume that $\mathsf P\neq\mathsf{NP}$. So you may want, still assuming $\mathsf P\neq\mathsf{NP}$, $L$ to be in $\mathsf{NP}\setminus\mathsf P$ and not $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. [Edit: Oh, I read your comment below, so your question seems to be: "Is that true that for all such $L$, the inequality occurs?", rather than "Does there exist such an $L$?" => I edit your question!]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depends on your definition of NPI. If A is incomplete for Turing reductions, the answer is yes since SAT is not in $P^A$.

If A is just many-one incomplete then we don't know how to prove it. We have a relativized world with there is a set A in NP such that A is not NP-complete via many-one reductions but SAT can be computed by a single query to A. (Theorem 1.9 in [this paper](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/newiso.pdf)).

Comment: Do you mean Theorem 1.9?

Comment: You are right. Fixed.